# How to slide toggle a pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

As you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZWmd/2/), when you click the menu button, the little triangle that points to the button is only shown after the animation has finished. I'd like the animation to start with the pseudo element and only then proceed to the drop-menu element. How can I accomplish this?

A solution doesn't necessarily have to use javascript, CSS3 will be most welcome, I'm not worried about compatibility issues.

Comment: The `slideToggle` hides the element completely. What if you use jQuery to just toggle the `height` using `animate`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery), although you might be able to achieve this with a mix of *both* JavaScript and CSS3, but I'm not sure how far you can get.

Comment: It's most certainly not a duplicate, but the answers to that question are pretty revealing of my ignorance. `pseudo-elements themselves are not part of the DOM, and thus you can't select and manipulate them directly with jQuery.` Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SZWmd/32/)

```
.drop-menu {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    top: -20px;
}

.drop-menu ul::before {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: 30px;
    border-width: 15px;
    border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
    border-style: solid;
}

.drop-menu ul {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this answer isn't that semantic because it doesn't use pseudo elements but the effect is so much smoother that I think I'll use this. Thanks!

Comment: @Ashitaka I've updated my answer to be smooth and semantic at the same time :) http://jsfiddle.net/SZWmd/32/

Answer (score 3):

See http://jsfiddle.net/SZWmd/23/

The problem is that while sliding, the element must have `overflow:hidden`, but then the triangle is hidden too.

Then, you have to slide `.drop-menu ul` instead of `.drop-menu`. You could easily do

```
$('.drop-menu-button').click(function() {
    $('.drop-menu').toggleClass('visible');
    $('.drop-menu ul').slideToggle();
});
```

and use this selector:

```
.drop-menu.visible::before
```

But the problem is that when is sliding up, the triangle is hidden at the beginning.

Then, you need

```
$('.drop-menu-button').click(function() {
    if($('.drop-menu').hasClass('visible')){
        $('.drop-menu ul').slideUp('',function(){
            $('.drop-menu').removeClass('visible');
        });
    }else{
        $('.drop-menu').addClass('visible');
        $('.drop-menu ul').slideDown();
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

You can also use

```
$('.drop-menu-button').click(function() {
    $('.drop-menu').addClass('visible');
    $('.drop-menu ul').slideToggle('',function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':visible')){
            $('.drop-menu').removeClass('visible');
        }
    });
});
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SZWmd/31/